# Increment or decrement array elements by 1

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity, increment, decrement

I need some help solving the following competitive programming question.
Given array A of size N .now you can make K operations where in each operation you can increase or decrease an element in array by 1. Now beauty of array is frequency of most frequent element in the array. Now output max beauty that can be achieved in K operations.
This function takes the following 3 parameters and returns the required answer
N- Represents the size of array nums
K- Represents the integer K
nums- Represents the elements of array nums
Input format for custom testing-

The first line contains T, which represents the number of test cases.
For each test case-
The first line contains N denoting the size of array nums
The second line contains integer K.
The third line contains N space-separated integers of array A

```
`Constraints:`1\<T\<10
1\<N\<1e5
0\<K\<1e18
\-1e9\<Ai\<1e9
\`
```

I tried the following approach , by sorting the array, then finding consecutive differences between them, to get max elements equal in k operations , I need to choose elements from index i to j such that no of operations are min and beauty is maximum.

Comment: You might have forgotten to ask a question. You describe (also show code of your attempts!) your approach but don't describe what's not working.

Comment: Question is to find max beauty that can be acheived in k operations. I didn't write any code as of now because i was not able to come up with logic first.

Comment: I think you are missing some thing here. `min(dict[i-1]+dict[i+1],k)` returns min of count , "k" . But our "k" is number of operations(where in each operation you can only choose an element and increment or decrement it by 1) being performed on particular element to make it equal to any other element.So comparing those two does not make sense.

Comment: Comparing that makes perfect sense. Consider an array like "1,1,2,2,2,3,3" and a `k` of 2. So you can transform your array to for instance "2,2,2,2,2,3,3" and the result is 5. The `min(...)` is to determine how many of the direct neighbors of 2 you can transform. There are 4 neighbors, but because of `k==2` you can only transform 2 of them

Comment: But you were right, I was missing something. Ie you can probably transform an element multiple times. Ie for an array like "1,3,3,3" and a `k` of 2 you can get an array of "3,3,3,3". But my initial approach would miss that

Comment: yes and I got an approach to solve it using binary search for finding size of beauty and sliding window to calculate number of operations.Anyways thanks for your help.I ll attach the code in answer.

Comment: Can you share the link of the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<int> preSum;

void calcPresum(vector<int>& v) {
    int n = v.size();
    preSum.clear(); preSum.resize(n, v[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        preSum[i] = preSum[i - 1] + v[i];
    }
}

int rangeSum(int i, int j) {
    if(i == 0) return preSum[j];
    return preSum[j] - preSum[i - 1];
}

int getCost(vector<int>& v, int st, int en, int mid) {
    int costLeft = (v[mid] * (mid - st + 1)) - rangeSum(st, mid);
    int costRight = rangeSum(mid, en) - (v[mid] * (en - mid + 1));
    return costLeft + costRight;
}

int costEq(vector<int>& v, int k) {
    int n = v.size(), ptr1 = 0, ptr2 = k - 1, cost = INT_MAX;
    for(; ptr2 < n; ptr2++, ptr1++) {
        // decide what is min cost in range ptr1 - ptr2
        // if odd elements median will give min cost
        if((ptr2 - ptr1 + 1) % 2 == 1) {
            cost = min(cost, getCost(v, ptr1, ptr2, (ptr1 + ptr2) / 2));
        }
        // if even elements check which median will give min cost
        else {
            cost = min({cost, getCost(v, ptr1, ptr2, (ptr1 + ptr2) / 2), getCost(v, ptr1, ptr2, (ptr1 + ptr2) / 2 + 1)});
        }
    }
    return cost;
}

int solve(vector<int> v, int k) {
    int n = v.size();
    int ptr1 = 1, ptr2 = n;
    calcPresum(v);
    while(ptr1 < ptr2) {
        int mid = ptr1 + (ptr2 - ptr1 + 1) / 2;
        if(costEq(v, mid) <= k) {
            ptr1 = mid;
        } else {
            ptr2 = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return ptr1;
}

int main() {
    // median gets the minimal cost for making all elements equal
    cout << solve({1, 4, 5, 7}, 4) << endl;
    cout << solve({1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7}, 4) << endl;
    cout << solve({1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7}, 2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).